# The emulator process for AVD Android_TV_1080p_API_30 has terminated for Mac

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-emulator, android-tv

Android Studio keeps showing the same error, only when I'm trying to add Android TV Virtual Device.
For other devices, I don't see that error.

I'm on a Mac and I've seen some other questions with same issue, but the suggested solution didn't work:

- I've made some space in my machine with now plenty of space available
  (30GB)
- I've uninstalled and reinstalled Android Emulator from SDK (30.8.4
  Installed)
- I've tried to install previous versions of Android Studio

I still have the same message here (this is with android-studio-2020.3.1.25-mac_arm.zip):
The emulator process for AVD Android_TV_1080p_API_30 has terminated.

I've also tried to add Android TV emulator using another Mac and I had no issues.
[image]

I've also noticed that in the other machine I had the Recommended tab populated (still with all x86 ABI), when in my machine I see nothing (only when trying adding Android TV):
[image]

Comment: For whomever is voting to close this as general computing, please [read the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) carefully: "software tools commonly used by programmers" are on-topic.  Questions about using software are only off-topic if they do not "directly involve tools used primarily for programming."

Answer (score 1):

TV emulator arm64 image is not available for M1. There is still have an issue on the google issue tracker platform.

You can check with https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/203238268?pli=1